# How to authenticate to the firebase's https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchImport with OAuth access token?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Does anyone know how to authenticate to the `batchImport` API of Firebase Instance ID Service (https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server) with Google Application Credential?

Or which IAM role is required to the service account associated with the credential?

The service account I currently used has a `Firebase Admin SDK Administrator Service Agent` role, and it is OK to authenticate to the `batchAdd` API, for example:

```
POST /iid/v1:batchAdd HTTP/1.1
Host: iid.googleapis.com
Authorization: Bearer {MY ACCESS TOKEN OF THE SERVICE ACCOUNT}
Content-Type: application/json
access_token_auth: true

Connection: close

{"to":"/topics/MY_FCM_TOPIC","registration_tokens":["MY_FCM_INSTANCE_TOKEN"]}
```

it responses 200 OK:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close

{"results":[{}]}
```

However, if I change to use the `batchImport` API with the same access token:

```
POST /iid/v1:batchImport HTTP/1.1
Host: iid.googleapis.com
Authorization: Bearer {MY ACCESS TOKEN OF THE SERVICE ACCOUNT}
Content-Type: application/json
access_token_auth: true

Connection: close

{"application":"MY iOS APP BUNDLE ID","sandbox":false,"apns_tokens":["MY_APNS_TOKEN"]}
```

it will response 401 Unauthorized:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close

{"error":"Not authenticated or unauthorized"}
```

Does the `batchImport` API not support authenticated with OAuth access token?

Or does my service account lack of some permissions?

Comment: Did you ever get a proper solution for this using service account? having the same issue

Comment: Having same issue, I suppose it's not yet supported ?

Answer (score 4):

To authenticate against `iid.googleapis.com` using an OAuth2 access token, instead of a FCM server key, it appears you also need to send the following header:

```
access_token_auth: true
```

The [Instance ID server reference docs](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server) fail to mention this. I had to dig into the [firebase-admin-node source code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/64f033683b79d19e96ab6c7bb085243a82e5c12a/test/unit/messaging/messaging.spec.ts#L323), which also makes requests to the IID service.

This header is also required for OAuth2 requests to the `/iid/info` endpoint:

```
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/token
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the hint i was looking for

Answer (score 3):

You must use your firebase api key.
You can find it in firebase under "settings -> Cloud Messaging"

There should be an API key visbile and a legacy API key.

Header: `Authorization: key=<KEY>`

Comment: Yes, the API Key works. However I would like to avoid using the API Key directly.

So it is not that my service account lacks of some permissions but the `v1:batchImport` just doesn't support be authenticated with OAuth access token?

Comment: I am running my code on GCP. I think using the GCP service account with minimal permissions from the metadata server is a more preferred way than injecting API Key into my runtime env.