# how to authenticate iid.googleapis.com with oauth2 access tokens

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-oauth, google-cloud-messaging

Im trying to use https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchImport to convert apns keys to fcm keys
but I kept getting

```bash
curl -X POST "https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchImport" \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer ya29.c.....Sh1' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'access_token_auth: true' \
  -d '
{
  "application": "com.example.sample.user",
  "sandbox":false,
  "apns_tokens":[
    "6d83c......9be83f1396"
  ]
}
  '
```

```
{"error":"Not authenticated or unauthorized"}
```

What I tried:
the scope I requested for

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
- I followed this guide in generating oauth2 keys https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account
- I used the google-auth-library to generate access tokens but it still doesnt work
- I even tried https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
- I have also read similar questions asked [How to authenticate to the firebase's https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchImport with OAuth access token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60323665/how-to-authenticate-to-the-firebases-https-iid-googleapis-com-iid-v1batchimp)